# Mysql UPDATE needs one more refresh to display values

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to update database using form. Here is the php code

```
require 'connect.php';
include_once('header.php');
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id");
$get = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if(isset($_REQUEST['value1'])){
    $value1 = $_REQUEST['value1'];
    $value2 = $_REQUEST['value2'];
    $value3 = $_REQUEST['value3'];


    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `value1` = $value1, `value2` = $value2 WHERE `id` = $id");

    if($update){
            $msg = "<div class=\"alert alert-success\">Server UPDATED Successfully.</div>";
        }else{
            $msg ="<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">Failed to Update server!</div>";
        }
```

It is working perfectly and updating the database. But once it shows "Server updated successfully." Below, it still shows old values in form.

How do i make the page or values reload after successful update?
    }

Comment: you need to move from using mysql to at least mysqli or pdo with prepared statements

Comment: @justbaron Ik, I am currently in developing phase, once the script is ready  I shall make all security changes! Thanks tho :)

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: " I am currently in developing phase". That's the best time to **STOP** using `mysql_query`. Code like this has a way of finding its way deployed to the public internet and getting exploited because you forget to fix it. Don't set yourself up for disaster. Do it right the first time and **every time** after that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check below code

```
    require 'connect.php';
    include_once('header.php');
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id");
    $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if(isset($_REQUEST['value1'])){
        $value1 = $_REQUEST['value1'];
        $value2 = $_REQUEST['value2'];
        $value3 = $_REQUEST['value3'];


        $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `value1` = $value1, `value2` = $value2 WHERE `id` = $id");

        if($update){

          $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id");
          $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                $msg = "<div class=\"alert alert-success\">Server UPDATED Successfully.</div>";
            }else{
                $msg ="<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">Failed to Update server!</div>";
            }
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Order of operations should be

- update
- select
- show

so you put the update part first (taking care to prevent sql injection):

```
require 'connect.php';
include_once('header.php');

$id = (integer) @$_GET['id'];
if (! empty($id)) {

  if (isset($_REQUEST['value1'])) {
    $value1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['value1']);
    $value2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['value2']);
    $value3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['value3']);

    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `value1` = '$value1', `value2` = '$value2' WHERE `id` = $id");

    if ($update) {
      $msg = "<div class=\"alert alert-success\">Server UPDATED Successfully.</div>";
    } else {
      $msg ="<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">Failed to Update server!</div>";
    }
  }
```

now you can do your select:

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id");
  $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

now you can show your page: